# KeyListener doesn't move "FillRect" on JPanel

Tags: java

I used the KeyListener interface on the KeyBoardInput class as given below :-

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyBoardInput implements KeyListener {
    
    public boolean WPressed, APressed, DPressed, SPressed;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        
        int pressedKeyNum = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            
            WPressed = true;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            
            APressed = true;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            
            SPressed = true;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            
            DPressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        int pressedKeyNum = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            
            WPressed = false;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            
            APressed = false;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            
            SPressed = false;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            
            DPressed = false;
        }
        
    }

}
```

but when I try to use it in a game loop, that is in the display class it doesn't work(I haven't included the whole display class to make my question shorter)

Here's the game loop :-

```
    Thread t;
    int playerX = 100;
    int playerSpeed = 4;
    int playerY = 100;
    public void startThread() {
        
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillRect(playerX,playerY,tileSide = tileSide*3,tileSide);
        g2.dispose();
        
    }
    public void update() {
        
        if(kb.WPressed == true) {
            
            playerY -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(kb.APressed == true) {
            
            playerX -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(kb.SPressed == true) {
            
            playerY += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(kb.DPressed == true) {
            
            playerX += playerSpeed;
        }
    }
    
    double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
    double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;
    
    public void run() {
        
        while(t != null) {
        
            update();
            repaint();
            
            
        }
            
    }
```

I can't define the problem really well, all I can say is I don't get a error, it draws the red rectangle, but the rectangle doesn't move.

***classes :-***

> Start.java

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import LCStudios.WhiteSouls.display.DisplayFrame;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        final int tileSide, tileArea, scale, finalTileSize, WindowX, WindowY;
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        
        tileSide = 16;
        tileArea = tileSide * tileSide; 
        scale = 3;
        finalTileSize = tileSide * 3;
        
        WindowX = finalTileSize * 20;
        WindowY = finalTileSize * 12;
        
        System.out.println(WindowX + " :: " + WindowY);
        
        f.setSize(WindowX,WindowY);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("WhiteSouls  ::  From LiveCrystal Studios");
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Code\\LC_lib\\WhiteSouls\\WhiteSouls 64x.png").getImage());
        f.add(new DisplayFrame());
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

> DisplayFrame.java

```
package LCStudios.WhiteSouls.display;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import LCStudios.WhiteSouls.background.KeyBoardInput;

public class DisplayFrame extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    
    int tileSide = 16;
    int tileArea = tileSide * tileSide; 
    int scale = 3;
    int finalTileSize = tileSide * scale;
    Thread t;
    public boolean running;
    int playerX = 100;
    int playerSpeed = 4;
    int playerY = 100;
    int FPS = 60;
    
    KeyBoardInput kb = new KeyBoardInput();
    
    
    
    public DisplayFrame() {
        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960,576));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(kb);
        this.setFocusable(true);
}
    
    public void startThread() {
        
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillRect(playerX,playerY,tileSide = tileSide*3,tileSide);
        g2.dispose();
        
    }
    public void update() {
        
        if(kb.WPressed == true) {
            
            playerY -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(kb.APressed == true) {
            
            playerX -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(kb.SPressed == true) {
            
            playerY += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(kb.DPressed == true) {
            
            playerX += playerSpeed;
        }
    }
    
    double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
    double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;
    
    public void run() {
        
        while(t != null) {
        
            update();
            repaint();
            
            
        }
            
    }

}
```

> KeyBoardInput.java

```
package LCStudios.WhiteSouls.background;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyBoardInput implements KeyListener {
    
    public volatile boolean WPressed, APressed, DPressed, SPressed;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        
        int pressedKeyNum = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            
            WPressed = true;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            
            APressed = true;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            
            SPressed = true;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            
            DPressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        int pressedKeyNum = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            
            WPressed = false;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            
            APressed = false;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            
            SPressed = false;
        }
        if(pressedKeyNum == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            
            DPressed = false;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: This question may be **broad** as I can't define this problem that well

Comment: Seems like a thread issue to me, try defining `WPressed`, `APressed`, `DPressed`, `SPressed` with the `volatile` keyword and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: ```public volatile boolean WPressed, APressed, DPressed, SPressed;``` in this format? because it still doesn't work. I am sure that the loop works

Comment: Yes! I cannot say too much about the code because there's not enough provided, but I'm assuming the boolean variables are being changed in the main thread, and they're being read on the thread that you created. Since one thread is changing the value, and the other is reading it, `volatile` could be a solution (if my assumption is correct).

Comment: @Hitler Steve Which class is the gameloop code written in? If it's written outside of `KeyBoardInput`, then you might have to declare the boolean variables as `static`

Comment: I will edit the post containing all the code, Done..

Comment: It is written in ```KeyBoardInput```

Comment: I see the problem now. The `run()` method in `DisplayFrame` never gets executed.

Comment: I went through your code, and wrote my answer below. Let me know if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed 3 problems in your code.

1. The `boolean` variables in `KeyBoardInput` class is used in 2 different threads.
2. The `run()` method in `DisplayFrame` never gets executed.
3. The `run()` method calls `update()` and `repaint()` without pausing. This will consume a large portion of your CPU usage.

The boolean variables are being changed at a keypress event. This means that the [EDT(Event Dispatching Thread)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is modifying the boolean variables in the `KeyBoardInput` class. However, the boolean variables are being read in `Thread t` *(which is declared in `DisplayFrame`.)* Since one thread is only modifying the variable and the other thread is only reading it, this can simply be resolved by using the `volatile` keyword.

```
public volatile boolean WPressed, APressed, DPressed, SPressed;
```

The constructor of `DisplayFrame` needs to call `startThread()` in order for your thread to start running. To do this, simply add `this.startThread()` in the `DisplayFrame` constructor.

```
public DisplayFrame() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960,576));
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    this.addKeyListener(kb);
    this.setFocusable(true);
        
    this.startThread();
}
```

Finally, the `run()` method in `DisplayFrame` should sleep for a bit. Otherwise, the thread will constantly be active, and it will result in heavy CPU usage. To resolve this, simply call `Thread.sleep()` in the while loop. *(This will make the thread sleep for a bit. If you change the argument to a smaller value, the square will move at a faster rate.)*

```
public void run() {
    while(t != null) {
        update();
        try {Thread.sleep(50);}
        catch (Exception e) {}
        repaint();
    }        
}
```

One last thing that I want to point out is the code in `DisplayFrame.paintComponent(Graphics g)`

```
g2.fillRect(playerX,playerY,tileSide = tileSide*3,tileSide);
```

I'm not sure what this code is meant to do, but I think it should be changed to this:

```
g2.fillRect(playerX,playerY,tileSide*3,tileSide*3);
```

I applied these changes, and the square moves properly at each keypress.

Comment: This fixed it, and I just didn't set the ```tileSize``` properly so I used ```g2.fillRect(playerX,playerY,tileSide = tileSide*3,tileSide);``` as a temporary solution

Comment: The first problem :- I watched a video, so I used it in 2 threads
I don't have a solution to the other both

Comment: Oh, using multiple threads to handle keypresses is not a major problem, I believe it's a common way to bind keypresses to certain actions. A lot of the times, it could work without having the `volatile` keyword. But I thought I'd address that because debugging multi-threaded programs is really frustrating sometimes.

Comment: *using multiple threads to handle keypresses is not a major problem, I believe it's a common way to bind keypresses to certain actions* - actually is it not common and is not the proper approach. 1) typically you would use `Key Bindings` NOT a KeyListener to listen for keyboard events. 2) All updates to a component or the properties of a component should be done on the EDT. So a Swing Timer should be used for animation, not a Thread. See: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for examples.